# Redirect started process output and print it back to console in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, redirect, console, output

I have a WinForms application. Inside that application I'm starting a new process, and I want the output of this particular process (not the whole winforms app) to be redirected to the console.
The native method `AllocConsole()` is not good enough for me, because it takes over control on the whole WinForms app, and when I close the console it closes also the GUI form.

I've tried to use `AttachConsole(int dwProcessId)`
and redirect the output to the console of the process I'm starting, but I can't figure out why it's not working.

I can't put `AttachConsole` in other places, because I can get the process Id only after the process is started to run.

Any suggestions?

P.S. I'm doing it because I need to do things with the output and also print it "live" to the user, If you have any other suggestions that is not related to what I wrote here I would be glad to hear them.

Thanks

```
public static void RedirectOutput(string program, string parameters)
{

    Process process = new Process();          

    process.StartInfo.FileName = program;
    process.StartInfo.Arguments = parameters;
    process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;

    process.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(OutputConsoleHandler);
    process.ErrorDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(OutputConsoleHandler);

    process.Start();

    AttachConsole(process.Id);

    process.BeginOutputReadLine();
    process.BeginErrorReadLine();
    process.WaitForExit();

}

public static void OutputConsoleHandler(object sendingProcess, DataReceivedEventArgs outLine)
{
    Console.WriteLine(outLine.Data);
}

[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
static extern bool AttachConsole(int dwProcessId);
```

Comment: Why insist on using a Console but not any TextBox as you are using WinForm?

Comment: @Tommy The original output is printed to console. I need to take the output and do things with it, but also let the user see the output as nothing happen

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement a Custom Trace Listener. inside this class spawn a console window and inside Write/Write Line method, you can print the content to the window